# Syncing between remote git repo and TFS VS 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I just started using a localized git repo for playing around with some experimental features, and optimizations I am working on with company codebase from my home PC. I was wondering what is the best way to sync this code back up to my PC at work where we use TFS?

I have tried using the "Publish to Visual Studio Team Services" feature to push my local repo up to our TFS server, but I am getting an error

> "VSS011031: There is no profile for the authenticated user in the
>   system."

(I wasn't able to find anything on this error from google search)...

Is this the correct/recommended way to go about it?

Comment: Have you configured your profile for your account? Can you sign in your VSTS team project from Web Portal?

Comment: Thank you, Yes, my profile for VSTS is configured, and I am able to sign in from the web portal.

Comment: Can you share your detailed steps? I just tried to create a local repo and use "Publish to Visual Studio Team Services" to push it to VSTS, didn't see any issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create two builds to sync your code between two git repositories.

https://nkdagility.com/open-source-vsts-tfs-github-better-devops/

1. Create a GitHub triggered build on your VSTS server and have it call:

`Git pull https://github.com/nkdAgility/VstsMigrator.git master
Git push https://personalToken@github.com/nkdAgility/VstsMigrator.git head:master`

2. Create a Build on the VSTS repo and add:

`Git pull https://:personaltoken@nkdagility.visualstudio.com/defaultProject/_git/VstsMigrationTools master
Git push https://:personaltoken@nkdagility.visualstudio.com/defaultProject/_git/VstsMigrationTools head:master`

YOu will need to get each sides personal access tokens...

Answer (score 1):

To push the local repo to VSTS from Visual Studio, you would need to be signed into VS with the identity you want to use with your VSTS account. Connect to your account with VS via Team Explorer.

The easiest way is going to be to add your account as a remote for Git and push the changes. See the "What if I don't have code already on a Git service like Visual Studio Team Services?" section of [Creating Git repositories with Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/creatingrepo).